# Pass file upload control as a parameter to a method

Tags: c#, file-upload, parameter-passing

I want to write a general file upload function in C#. My website has more than 20 columns divided into tabs consisting of nearly 8 - 10 file upload controls. 
 I would like to write a general method into which i could pass the fileupload control, posted file & location to be saved. How do i pass the fileupload control to a method ?

```
public string uploadMethod(HttpPostedFile file, <fileUpload control>, string saveLocation)
{
  //saving code
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uploadMethod(FileUpload1.PostedFile, <fileUpload control>, saveFolder)
}
```

I know how to save the path but have no clue how to pass a fileupload control as a parameter to a method. Would be grateful for your help :)

Comment: You might also Google "[dependency injection](https://www.google.com/search?q=dependency+injection&rlz=1C1DVCC_enUS346&aq=0&oq=dependancy+&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)".  Common objects should be injected into classes that need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the answer after playing around a bit. Following is the solution...

```
private void uploadDoc(HttpPostedFile httpPostedFile, int filesize, string saveLocation, System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload FileUpload1)
{
  //code for saving the file
}
```

And this is how we pass the parameters to the function...

```
uploadDoc(FileUpload1.PostedFile, filesize, saveLocation, FileUpload1);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public string uploadMethod(HttpPostedFile file, FileUpload FU, string saveLocation)
{
string path = FU.FileName;
}
```

Comment: how do i declare the fileupload while calling the uploadmethod ?

Comment: @sorry i dont understand can you please explain with your code

Comment: how do i write it here...


protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    uploadMethod(what do i write here ?)

}

Comment: @AmitPhilips try this. protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
uploadMethod( file, nameoffileuploadcontrol, saveLocation)
{
//saving code
}
 }

Comment: i tried that but it says the method has invalid arguments....
code:
uploadMethod(FileUpload1.PostedFile, filesize, url, FileUpload1);

Comment: following is the code:

public void uploadDoc(HttpPostedFile file, int size, string url, FileUpload FU1)
{
}

and...
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
 uploadDoc(FileUpload1.PostedFile, filesize, url, FileUpload1);
}

Comment: @AmitPhilips check whether all the parameter type matches

Comment: can you mention how you would pass the parameters :)